# Add tags to track customer activity(open/clicks) in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-studio, email-tracking, tag

I am sending emails through Journey Builder. What kind of tagging method should I follow in order to track the customer activity such as opens & clicks. Also how to add these tags?

Answer (score 1):

There is a data view for both opens and clicks that can be used in SQL Activity to extract this information.

Tagging is for content organization. Here is a Salesforce Help Article on Tags: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_tags.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

SFMC tracks the clicks for all the links included in the email automatically and you can extract the click data from _click data views so you don't need to anything extra for this.

To track the opens - You have to do following things -

1. You have to add below code in the email, this can be added by using insert code tool as well, you can find this option in the same email message which you want to track for opens.

`<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking"/>`

2. You have to add at least one image because the open tracking pixel depends on image loading for the data to be collected in SFMC.

You can find more information here [SF Click and Email Behavior](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_clicks_and_opens_behavior.htm&type=5)